# Handling Android implicit activity crashes

Tags: android, android-intent, android-implicit-intent

I start the implicit activity in this way:

```
  Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(miniGameSceneStatus.getPackageName());
        context.startActivity(launchIntent);
```

If this activity finish I receive a broadcast, but if the activity crashes I can't see anything except it returns to the first activity without any problem.

Is there any way to know what is happening in the second activity?

Comment: You could use `startActivityForResult()` if the `Activity` you are calling can return a result instead of a broadcast. In this way you can determine if it was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap up your code with null check before to get context and miniGameSceneStatu and your activity will not get crashed.

```
    if (context != null && miniGameSceneStatus != null) {
        Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(miniGameSceneStatus.getPackageName());

      context.startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

1. Check camera permission before to do any action

   ```
   //Camera permission required for Marshmallow version                                
   if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), 
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

   // Callback onRequestPermissionsResult                                     
   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityName.this,
                                       new String[ {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA);}
   ```

Comment: The problem is not about launching a new activity. The problem is when the launched activity crashes, and I want to know why. For example, when you start the camera app for taking a picture, but it crashes before the photo shot.

Comment: @PéterKovács Please share your log cat with me so I can help you out.